# Cloudbees dev cloud + Postgresql + rubygems pg (native extension) how to use?

Tags: postgresql, cloudbees, pg

I want to use postgres in cloudbees dev cloud, I read this article:
http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/PostgreSQL

But, I run `bundle`, I got error:

> Installing pg (0.15.1) .......
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking for pg_config... no No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
> ```
>
> --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/   --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
>     --with-pg   --without-pg    --with-pg-dir   --without-pg-dir
>     --with-pg-include   --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>     --with-pg-lib   --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/     --with-pg-config
>     --without-pg-config     --with-pg_config    --without-pg_config
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/jenkins/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /home/jenkins/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/gem_make.out An error
>   occurred while installing pg (0.15.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.15.1'` succeeds before bundling.

What do I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use single shell script, and I declare once at the top:

```
export POSTGRESQL_VERSION=9.2.4
curl -s -o use-postgresql https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/postgresql/use-postgresql
source ./use-postgresql
```

Then I don't necessary pass environment variables between shells.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to resolving this:

1) Use the workaround above, by adding

```
PATH=/scratch/jenkins/postgresqls/postgresql-9.2.4-x86_64/bin:$PATH
```

This is not ideal as we are *just* about to move that path to support pull-request builds

2) Combine the two steps

In your build you will need to combine the PostgreSQL and Ruby installation steps so that the environment is configured properly.

I personally recommend using a script to do the build - `./bin/run-ci` - as opposed to typing everything into Jenkins.

This keeps your build process change controlled and documented - and lets you roll out changes across multiple build servers quite rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

My work around:

Set PATH above bundle, and 9.2.4 is my installing version.

`PATH=/scratch/hudson/postgresqls/postgresql-9.2.4-x86_64/bin:$PATH`

Then I can bundle completed :)